# What is the best data structure to store location information?

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, location

I am building a simple app that all is does is storing the 'location' from CLLocation every hout. I am very new to objective C, and just wanted to know which structure would be ideal for this purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want an lightweight structure to store thousands of locations, create a C struct with just the fields you need. If you only need lat and long, you can just use CLLocationCoordinate2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends by what you have to do with that:

- if you have to have them ordered (by the timestamp, for example) an array is good
- if you have to retrieve them using a sort of key, a dictionary is good
- if you have only to collect them, a set is better (think of `NSSet`)

Keep in mind that `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and `NSSet` only store objects.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. All I want to do is to store my locations in an array based on time stamp. It doesnt really matter. It should be a list of hundreds of locations, which I will later save to a file (and hopefully plot on google earth, but I am WAYYY far away from that). For now, I just need to understand what kind of array or data structure should I use for those locations (basically, lat/long/time, but want to keep it flexible)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, for 2D coordinates `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, or if you want altitude also you can use this:

```
typedef struct {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D ground,
  double altitude;
} CLLocationCoordinate2DWithAltitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any point to having these locations? Are you going to be implementing any specific algorithm with them?

If all I was doing was storing arbitrary locations, I would probably wrap them with a "location" object, and then store the location object within a linked list or array.

If you are going to try to resolve the locations to logical addresses, then you may want to store them in an adjacency matrix or list (two dimensional array) so you can perform graph operations on them (such as shortest path algorithms).

Linked list implementation can be found here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?LinkedList

This isn't an array, it is a more advanced data structure. It is very commonly used, because there is no limit to the size of the data structure.

Comment: Nop, not any post processing of the locations. Simple as it sounds. Could you please refer to a sample code for writing so such an array that has an unknown size? (the plan is to basically "dump" the file when the user quits the app).

Comment: For your current needs all you need to do is store your CLLocation objects into an NSMutableArray. The code to create such an array is NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithCapacity: 512]; And to add items you would do [myArray addObject: locObj]; Eventually you could store this array out to file, even though you indicated you are not interested in that yet.

Comment: I am interested in storing it into a file. But why should I use NSMutableArray and not NSArray simply? What about the size? I wont know how big it will be - can I just append objects? Thanks!!

Comment: NSMutable is probably an array capable of being resized (however resizing an array is an expensive procedure because you are recreating the array everytime you resize it). I updated my original answer with a link to an implementation of linked-lists.

Comment: So I did the following in my view controller .m file and I am getting an array with null: in the ViewDidLoad method, I initiated the array:     NSMutableArray *locationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];, then later (in the locationUpdate method) I do this:     [locationArray addObject:location]; Why is not storing the locations?

Comment: Any idea why this thing doesnt work:     CLLocationCoordinate2D *loc;
    loc = location.coordinate; Where 'location' is a CLLocation object. thanks!